# stop async task after 60 second

Tags: java, android, dialog, timeout, android-asynctask

i want to stop async task after 60 second

i know there is a method get(time , timeunit) which i should be using in doInBackground 
but i dont know how to check if the time out has reached or not please provide that sample one line code .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you already know how to abandon the task after n seconds, but you need to know IF it was abandoned?

According to [AsyncTask docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) it'll throw a TimeoutException.

Do something like:

```
try {
    //your AsyncTask code
} catch(TimeoutException ex) {
    //your timeout code
}
```

Comment: well yes i got it i had to write return statement in catch block.

Answer (score 4):

you can use a `TimerTask` to which you can start in the `doInBackround()` with the schedule for 60 seconds. in the `run()` of the `TimerTask` just call the stop for the async task.